# Move Part from image outside the container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to move part form Image outside the container in flutter I tried many times and failed this is the final photo and also the number between the icons I need to center it and I tried align , text align and failed to one more thing the elevation of the container how can I do it I will convert this design into Grid View but I need to learn it so this the last step that I will do

[image]

```
const SizedBox(
                height: 32,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 176,
                height: 220,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: HexColor('#FFFFFF'),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                    //image and Icons
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Image(
                          image: photo1,
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              number--;
                              print(number);
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.remove,
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 7,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '$number',
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontFamily: 'robotto',
                          ),
                          //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 7,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              number++;
                              print(number);
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.add,
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      'GARDENIA PLANT',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontFamily: 'robotto',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: What is the parent widget of this ?

Comment: of all the screen Column but for the design which is image text ..etc is Container with width 176 and height 220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your `Image` with `Transform` to render the ui a little left or the position you want .

```dart
Transform.translate(
  offset: Offset(-22,0),
  child: Image(
    image: photo1,
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  ),
),
```

And use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,` on Row.

To align text use `textAlign: TextAlign.center,`

Also if need more placement UI, you can use `Stack` widget.

Comment: It did not work the photo moves to the left not up and i need it to move up for 58

Comment: using transform only render the item, you might go for stack widget